# Can I solder any module onto a PCB?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, soldering, bluetooth-low-energy

I was wondering if I'd be able to solder complete modules onto a PCB...

E.g. BLE module, GPS module, Accelero/Baro modules, etc.

If not, what components can I use to get these features?

Comment: Yes, if the pcb is routed to accept the module you're trying to attach.

Comment: [ESP12E solder onto a PCB](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cf-L18elrrM/VUSb5STOysI/AAAAAAAANTY/THPKnZuwU2E/s1600/ESP-12_b.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

Obviously nobody can answer this since we have no idea what your soldering capabilities are, and what equipment is available.  Actually *think* about it.

As for whether it is generally possible or advisable, no, not in the general case.

Some "modules" are specifically designed to be mounted on another PCB.  In that case, yes, it's obviously possible for someone to solder them who has sufficient soldering skill and equipment.

Modules that are meant for being soldered to a PCB are usually clearly sold as such.  They usually have what look like half cut off thru hole pads along the outside.  These are called *castellations* or sometimes *crenellations*, and are meant to provide good solder contact.  They can be reflow soldered.

Comment: I think the term is `castellations`, but maybe `crenellations` are a synonym? I haven't seen that before though.

Comment: @Jash: You maybe right.  Now that you mention it, "castellations" sound more right, although I've heard people say "crenellations" too, perhaps incorrectly.

Comment: @Jash: I just looked up both words, and they both seem to refer to notches in turrets and tops of castles.  This may be why either word is sometimes used.  I think I've heard "castellations" more often though.

Comment: Yeah, I also looked it up and found the turret/castle definition, along with this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/295443/81225. Of course that post is also just guessing as to the correct term, but meh. I'm sure both are correct.

Comment: @Jash: I updated the answer to include both terms.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned elsewhere, soldering complete modules onto your PCB is possible, within limits, depending on the nature of the module. The pros and cons of that have already been mentioned in Olin's answer and others.

I'd also add though, if this is for a product, it is not an approach you should follow lightly. The issue is, these modules come and go and or change over time. By blindly using them in your product you leave yourself wide open to suddenly no longer being able to get the devices and having to redesign your product with an intermediate loss of production or worse functionality.

For many of the plug-in type modules available, schematics are also provided. When that is the case, it is far better to copy said circuit into your own schematic rather than attempt to bolt it on.

Of course, some modules are of a higher function and contain proprietary logic or software designs. In those cases integration is not possible without coming to some legal agreement that includes support from the manufacturer. Using the product as a bolt-on you should, at the very least, contact the manufacturer to determine where the product is in it's expected life cycle. Don't make the mistake of... "By the time I got the design ready for production, the module manufacturer stopped making that part..!"

If the manufacturer is unknown..eg, "I found this gizmo on E-Bay" or the module is at or near the end of it's production life, don't even think about it unless it's a small run and you can find and afford to buy enough stock and spares up front to last the life of your widget.